# Pythonic way to populate a dictionary from list of records

Tags: python

**Background**

I have a module called `db.py` that is basically consist of wrapper functions that make calls to the db. I have a table called nba and that has columns like `player_name` `age` `player_id` etc.

I have a simple function called `db_cache()` where i make a call to the db table and request to get all the player ids. The output of the `response` looks something like this

```
[Record(player_id='31200952409069'), Record(player_id='31201050710077'), Record(player_id='31201050500545'), Record(player_id='31001811412442'), Record(player_id='31201050607711')]
```

Then I simply iterate through the list and dump each item inside a dictionary.

I am wondering if there is a more **pythonic way to populate the dictionary**?

**My code**

```
  def db_cache():
        my_dict: Dict[str, None] = {}
        response = db.run_query(sql="SELECT player_id FROM nba")
        for item in response:
            my_dict[item.player_id] = None
        return my_dict
    
    
    my_dict = db_cache()
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the dictionary? Why are the values initialized to `None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is built-in to the `dict` type:

```
>>> help(dict.fromkeys)
Help on built-in function fromkeys:

fromkeys(iterable, value=None, /) method of builtins.type instance
    Create a new dictionary with keys from iterable and values set to value.
```

The `value` we want is the default of `None`, so all we need is:

```
my_dict = dict.from_keys(db.run_query(sql="SELECT player_id FROM nba"))
```

Note that the `value` will be reused, and *not* copied, which can cause problems if you want to use a mutable `value`. In these cases, you should instead simply use the dict comprehension, as given in @AvihayTsayeg's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_arr = [1,2,3,4]
my_dict = {"item":item for item in my_arr}
```